# MarkLogic - mlcp job failing with return code 0

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp

MarkLogic version - 9.0-6.2

When I run the below mlcp code (TestLoad.sh) through our enterprise scheduler Zena (similar to Control-M), the Zena job is failing even though the mlcp is completed successfully and all the records ingested into STAGING DB.

```
Command '"./TestLoad.sh"'
failed with return code 0 and error message
```

### MLCP Code (TestLoad.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
mlcp.sh import -ssl \
-host localhost \
-port 8010 \
-username uname \
-password pwd \
-mode local \
-input_file_path /inputfilepath/test \
-input_file_type documents \
-aggregate_record_namespace "http://new.webservice.namespace" \
-output_collections test \
-output_uri_prefix /test/ \
-transform_module /ext/transform.sjs
```

I added 'exit 0' at the end of my bash script but still getting the same failure message.

Is this something I could handle within my mlcp script?

Comment: Are you using latest MLCP? I remember there were changes to MLCP regarding this..